# Codeigniter Pagination - first page always remain as the current page

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination, uri, config

I am having issue with with just the link of my codeigniter page

I have tired

```
$config=array();
$config['base_url']=base_url().'search-products?q='.$check_result;
//$check_result holds the search content of the user

$config['per_page']=5;
$config['use_page_numbers']=TRUE;
$config['query_string_segment']='p' ;
$config['page_query_string']=TRUE;
$config['total_rows]=$this->Views_Model->fetchSearchAdsTotal();
$this-pagination->initialize($config);
$data['page_links']=$this->pagination->create_link();
```

All the different pages fetches well but the main issue is the link structure

Given all the above code, if for instance, I am on page 8, it will still be showing 1 as the active

E.g **1** 2 3 Next Last

Even if am on page 10, it will still remain in the above format and first page will be the current active page

Also my url is something like this: localhost/Folder/search-items?q=SearchText&p=3

In my config.php

```
$config['enable_query_string']=TRUE;
$config['allow_get_array'] =TRUE
```

I don't know if the issue is due to the absence of the $config['uri_segment'] in the pagination configuration

Comment: Which version of Codeigniter are you running?

Comment: I am using codeigniter 3